# Does taipy python library display camera streaming and maps?

Tags: taipy

I am new to taipy in python, can I display an ip camera or any other camera streaming in a card within the web page?
Can i display a map, like google map, and insert a live updated locations to it? show a route on it?
I have looked for an example in the tutorials but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taipy charts are based on Plotly so it supports many different types of charts and maps. You can see an example on this [page](https://covid-dashboard.taipy.cloud/Map) of this [demo](https://www.taipy.io/project/covid-dashboard/). A [section of the documentation](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/charts/map/) explains how you can create maps. The background on the examples can be changed to be Google Maps.

In fact, some people already used it to create routes on Taipy maps.

You can also include camera streaming into Taipy as an external library. You can view it in this [demo](https://www.taipy.io/project/face-recognition/) that uses your camera.